# SQL how to combine the results into colums instead of 3 queries

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using a table with 3 fields: Id(Integer), Intensity(Integer), Activity_Minute(DateTime). I want to query a table that is grouped by Activity_Minute after extracting the time from the datetime so that each record is a minute of the day. Then I want the other 3 fields to be Intensity1, Intensity2, and Intensity3 that returns the sums of each intensity level (1-3) for each minute.

A sample of the table looks like this:

| Intensity | Activity_Minute | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2016-04-16T00:01:00 | 2873212765 |
| 1 | 2016-04-16T00:01:00 | 6290855005 |
| 3 | 2016-04-16T00:01:00 | 8792009665 |
| 1 | 2016-04-16T00:02:00 | 2873212765 |
| 1 | 2016-04-16T00:02:00 | 6290855005 |
| 3 | 2016-04-16T00:02:00 | 8792009665 |

This code was successful and I can replicate it for Intensity2 and Intensity3, but I'm not sure how to combine the 3 codes to return the results on 1 table.

```
SELECT 
  EXTRACT(TIME FROM Activity_Minute) AS Minute,
  SUM(Intensity) AS Intensity1
FROM `bellabeat-case-study-385200.fitbit_data.minute_intensities_narrow` 
WHERE Intensity = 1
GROUP BY Minute
ORDER BY Minute
```

| Minute | Intensity1 |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00:00 | 40 |
| 00:00:01 | 41 |
| 00:00:02 | 36 |

I tried this code but got the error: Unrecognized name for Intensity2 and Intensity3.

```
SELECT
  Minute,
  Intensity1,
  Intensity2,
  Intensity3
FROM (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(TIME FROM Activity_Minute) AS Minute,
    SUM(Intensity) AS Intensity1
  FROM `bellabeat-case-study-385200.fitbit_data.minute_intensities_narrow` 
  WHERE Intensity = 1
  GROUP BY Minute
) 
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(TIME FROM Activity_Minute) AS Minute,
    SUM(Intensity/2) AS Intensity2
  FROM `bellabeat-case-study-385200.fitbit_data.minute_intensities_narrow` 
  WHERE Intensity = 2
  GROUP BY Minute
) 
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(TIME FROM Activity_Minute) AS Minute,
    SUM(Intensity/3) AS Intensity3
  FROM `bellabeat-case-study-385200.fitbit_data.minute_intensities_narrow` 
  WHERE Intensity = 3
  GROUP BY Minute
) 
ORDER BY Minute;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below query

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(TIME FROM Activity_Minute) AS Minute,
    SUM(if(Intensity=1,Intensity, null)) AS Intensity1,
    SUM(if(Intensity=2,Intensity, null)) AS Intensity2,
    SUM(if(Intensity=3,Intensity, null)) AS Intensity3,
  FROM `bellabeat-case-study-385200.fitbit_data.minute_intensities_narrow` 
  GROUP BY Minute
```

but there is a more elegant solution with PIVOT

```
with t as (

  select 2 as intensity,timestamp('2016-04-16T00:01:00') as Activity_Minute, 2873212765 as id
  union all 
  select 1 as intensity,timestamp('2016-04-16T00:01:00') as Activity_Minute, 6290855005 as id
  union all 
  select 3 as intensity,timestamp('2016-04-16T00:01:00') as Activity_Minute, 8792009665 as id
  union all 
  select 1 as intensity,timestamp('2016-04-16T00:02:00') as Activity_Minute, 2873212765 as id
  union all 
  select 1 as intensity,timestamp('2016-04-16T00:02:00') as Activity_Minute, 6290855005 as id
  union all 
  select 3 as intensity,timestamp('2016-04-16T00:02:00') as Activity_Minute, 8792009665 as id
)
select * from (
  -- #1 from dimensions
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(TIME FROM Activity_Minute) AS Minute,
    intensity
  FROM t
)
PIVOT 
(
  -- #2 sum
  SUM(intensity) AS Intensity
  -- #3 pivot_column
  FOR Intensity in (1,2,3)
)
```

it returns

[image]